# Tabbar Controller shows Black screen when presentviewcontroller ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am currently working on tabbar application which has like 4 tabs. When I select one of the tab I want the behavior like how Instagram does when they click on "Camera tab" which I have achieved it by adding the code as below. But When I hit the tab; it shows a black screen first and then the view below. How can I avoid to not show the black screen ?

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
   if item.title == "More" {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
        let moreView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("moreView") as! MoreView;
        moreView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
        self.presentViewController(moreView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

var next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("moreView") as! MoreView

In place of:
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);

give background color to class that you are presenting 
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

Comment: same thing still.also I moved the implementation to Storyboard but it behaves the same.

Comment: so the issue is when I select tab item "more"; there is this background view on which the MoreView is presented. When I cancel the moreview, and stay on the same tab I see there is a black background view. If I select background to white color; it will make MoreView to be white but not the background view.

Comment: Just created a demo code . Working fine . can share it send me the mail id

Comment: It still doesnt work the way I am explaining....I think there is another way of doing it...